# laravel 8 Eloquent query builder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm making an attempt to write Eloquent join query but i didn't get the result i wanted.

i have 2 table

1. `products` which contains all information about products
2. `category_product` contains `product_id` and `category_id`

i just want to select all information about products which their `category_id` is equal to 2

[image: products table]

[image: category_product table]

Comment: Have you set `belongsToMany` relations in both models?

Comment: try with `belongsToMany` category relation and `whereHas` condition to filter records.

Comment: Please add more context to your question and share the relations you've applied between the models and the code you're applying the join with

Comment: yes i set `blongsToMany` relations in both models

Answer (score 0):

After you have `belongsToMany` relation between `categories` and `products`.

```
Product::whereHas('categories', function($query){
    $query->where('id',2);
})->with('categories')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I can offer you a solution like this

```
class Product extends Model
{
    
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(Category::class, 'category_product table');
    }
}

class Category extends Model
{
   
    public function product()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Product::class, 'category_product table');
    }

}
```

in Controller

```
$products = DB::table('products')
            ->join('category_product', 'products.id', '=', 'category_product.products_id')
            ->select('products.*')
            ->where('category_product.category_id','=',2)
            ->get();
```

Comment: Why do you create relations if you are just going to use the DB facade..?